# Use a route with the same pattern from another bundle

Tags: symfony, routes

I have two routes in two different bundles with the same pattern. As the documentation says, only the first route is used.

route 1 is in a bundle named KitStyleBundle

route 2 is in another bundle (I dont know the name, it could be added by the developpers and represent the application they have to develop)

Question : Normally route 1 is used, but if a route 2 is defined in another bundle, I would like this route to be used. Is it possible to change the order of loading with routes. Or is there any other way to achieve what I want to ?

Comment: By loading the second bundle later, you can override a route by giving to it the same name.

Comment: good... can you give it as an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Routes are not automatically loaded. You can simply change the order of the include statements in your routing config file (app/config/routing.yml)

Comment: my routes are in the routing.yml of each bundle. as I am not the one who adds the second route.. I cannot do as you say

Comment: That's correct. How come can't you access the importation of the routes in `app/config/routing.yml` ?